# I'm trying to center Image in custom UITableViewCell but it sticks to left side no matter what

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I've created a cell prototype in the Xcode 4.2 storyboard that consists of an image view in the center of the cell and some text below it but when I run the app the image is always moved to the left side.  I've made the cell extra tall to ensure it wasn't a height issue.  I also played with the autosize settings.

So far nothing I've tried will make the image move to the center of the tableViewCell when the code is actually running.

Note, this is done purely in the StoryBoard.  The only code I've written is code to create a list of objects with a "name" and "image" and the minimum table view source/delegate code so I can fill in two entries in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something that works just fine in iOS 4.x, but was doing something similar to what you describe in the iOS 5 simulator, moving a UIImageView down by about 120px for no apparent reason. Setting the Autosizing settings to have the top position outside the box frozen (if that makes sense) fixed the issue—though it was not at all clear to me why this behavior had changed in iOS 5 vs. previously.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer because it did work for you at least.  For me, I decided this way was probably going to be too much effort and switched to a whole different approach.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use something like :

```
static NSString *identifier = @"ImageRecordCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UIImageView *pic = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];

label.text = @"test";
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

return cell;
```

be sure not to set tag to zero